# Safari - wrong content-type on AJAX form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, multipartform-data

I use the following code to submit a form to a server (it's Dojo's xhr):

```
var fd = new FormData();
//appending info to form data
xhr("/api/method.json", {
                method: "POST",
                handleAs: "json",
                headers: {'Content-Type': false}, //need for disable set x-www-form-urlencoded and normal work formdata
                data: fd
            })
```

And it work fine under Chrome or Firefox. However, it doesn't work under Safari (v. 6.0.5)!

The problem is in content-type: **Safari sets it to 'application/xml'**, while **Chrome and Firefox set it to 'multipart/form-data' with correct boundary**.

Is there any way to fix this?

And by the 'way to fix this' I don't mean 'constructing request headers and body with my bare hands'.

Comment: `false` is not a valid `Content-Type` what is your Content-Type? Just use "multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen it is 'multipart/form-data'. However, by 'Content-Type': false, I'm not actually setting Content-Type to false, but rather telling xhr not to set Content-Type at all, so that browser can make it by itself.

Comment: How's that working out for you?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen if I set content-type to 'multipart/form-data' it still doesn't work, but now in every browser. When using 'multipart/form-data' one should also specify a boundary, and construct a request body using that boundary. And that is what I meant by 'constructing request with my bare hands'.